# Why would security credentials sometimes be missing from EC2 metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-iam

I'm using the boto library, version info:

```
boto==2.38.0
botocore==0.81.0
```

I'm using `boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()` on an EC2 instance its metadata in order to use the security credentials that I've associated with the instance.  Sometimes the credentials are there under `meta_data['iam']['security-credentials']['ROLE_NAME']`, but other times 'security-credentials' just points to an empty dictionary.

Any suggestions/explanations out there besides try `boto3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out, it's because `boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()` returns an instance of `<class 'boto.utils.LazyLoadMetadata'>` and not a true `dict`.  Its internal `dict` structures are also members of `LazyLoadMetadata`  For data that  can be fetched lazily, the iterators provided by this class appear to only return items/values that have already been explicitly accessed.  Because credentials associated with instances are temporary, it makes sense that they would be fetched lazily.

Example:

```
>>> import boto.utils
>>> meta_data = boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()
>>> creds = meta_data.get('iam', {}).get('security-credentials', {})
>>> debug_vals = list(creds.iteritems())
>>> debug_vals
[('ROLE_NAME', None)]
>>>
>>> creds  # printing the object evaluates/loads the entire 'tree'
{'ROLE_NAME': {u'Code': u'Success', u'LastUpdated': u'2015-10-20T15:19:27Z', u'AccessKeyId': u'AQW...', u'SecretAccessKey': u'LmA...', u'Token': u'AQ...', u'Expiration': u'2015-10-20T21:36:17Z', u'Type': u'AWS-HMAC'}}
>>> 
>>> 
>>> debug_vals  # old instance was already populated, so it won't change
[('ROLE_NAME', None)]
>>>
>>> debug_vals2 = list(creds.iteritems())  # a new call to iteritems gets the fully loaded tree
>>> debug_vals2
[('ROLE_NAME', {u'Code': u'Success', u'LastUpdated': u'2015-10-20T15:19:27Z', u'AccessKeyId': u'AQW...', u'SecretAccessKey': u'LmA...', u'Token': u'AQ...', u'Expiration': u'2015-10-20T21:36:17Z', u'Type': u'AWS-HMAC'}}]
# THE END
```

So if you access them directly, you'll find the expected values.  If you iterate over them, you could end up with surprises.